# see airflow ui in Docker

Tags: docker, airflow

This is gonna sound stupid probably but...

I'm trying to run `airflow` on a windows machine.
I'm aware that `airflow` doesn't work on windows so i thought I'd use `docker`.

So after installing docker in windows, i opened up my cmd and type:

```
docker pull puckel/docker-airflow:1.10.9
docker container run --name airflow-docker -it puckel/docker-airflow:1.10.9 /bin/bash
```

That image already contains `python` and `airflow` ( https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow)
Then

```
airflow initdb
airflow webserver -p 8080
```

Everything seems fine.
I tried to visit`localhost:8080` on chrome but nothing shows up.
I don't know where i'm supposed to see airflow ui.

I should expose port 8080 to see it?
How can i do?

Thanks.

Other resources:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=20HDFbYyAY0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the port 8080 to be exposed to the host you could use `-p` parameter in docker run commannd. Also you can set the command `webserver` directlry while starting the container. This will start Airflow with Sequential Executor.

```
docker run --name airflow-docker -d -p 8080:8080 puckel/docker-airflow:1.10.9 webserver
```